# Create a form inside a form

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to create a form inside a form (without javascript/jquery).

I have list with invoices. Each invoice has an Id and an InvoiceNumber, there is also a list Details.

```
public class Invoice
{
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(CombGuidGenerator))]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("InvoiceNumber")]
    public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }

    public List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}
```

In the list Details, there are two items: another Id and an DetailNumber

```
public class Detail
{
        [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(CombGuidGenerator))]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("DetailNumber")]
        public int DetailNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is: you can have only one invoice (so only one InvoiceNumber), but inside that invoice, you can have multiple details.

This is my Edit / Create page (the first I also use to create a new invoice:

```
@model ProjectInvoice.Models.Invoice

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New Note</legend>
        <h3>New Note</h3>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InvoiceNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InvoiceNumber)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
         @foreach (ProjectInvoice.Models.Detail detail in Model.Details)
         {
            @Html.EditorFor(model => detail.DetailNumber)
         }
    </fieldset>
}
```

Currently, I am only trying to display the detail input field for DetailNumber. But this doesn't work, and I don't know why and how I can fix this

Comment: we should have only one form tag in our page but we have multiple field set

Comment: Yes, but I wan't to create a form inside a form, so I have to use tow form tags right?

Comment: Creating form inside form is anti pattern.

Comment: Creating form with in form is malcious.you cant do like this.

Comment: But i should be able to add multiple "details" inside my "invoice"